# Merge two linear functions

Tags: functions

I have two functions

f1= 45.7*x - 600 and
f2= -0.426*x +240

If I plot them in the same plot I got [Plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCsvE.png)

I want to kind of combine them together so I got something like [Plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H5XA.png)

However I am not quite sure how the equation of the function on plot 2 will look like based on the coefficients of my two functions. Can someone help me out with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f1=f2\iff 45.7\cdot x-600=-0.426\cdot x+240 \iff 45.7\cdot x+0.426\cdot x=240+600$$
$$\iff x=\frac{840}{46.126}\approx18.211.$$
So your functions intersect at the point with x-coordinate $18.211$. The function your plot2 shows is thus
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}f_1(x)\ \mbox{ if }\ x\leq18.211\\ f_2(x)\ \mbox{ if }\ x>18.211 \end{cases}$$
How to plot this function depends on the software you are using.

Comment: Thansk for your answer. I also get this breakpoints values. I was wondering is there is any function which can achieve plot2 instead of using a piecewise linear function like you did?

Comment: No, there is not. There is no equivalent form of $f(x)$ that is not piecewise, such that plot2 can only be achieved by this piecewise function. For what purpose are you after something other than the piecewise function? Because any software can easily deal with these kind of functions.

Comment: I just want to constrain a model response with a function which looks like plot2. I am working with R.

Comment: I am not familiar with R, or the thing you want to do. So I can't help you any further with that, sorry. Maybe someone else can? I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788050/how-to-define-a-piecewise-function-in-r) though, maybe that can be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_1=ax+b$ and $f_2=cx+d$ with $a \neq c$, then what you call Plot2 is given by the graph of the function $f$ defined as follows: $f(x)=f_1(x)$ for $x \leq (d-b)/(a-c)$ and $f(x)=f_2(x)$ else.